# updating firefox on debian

Tags: sudo, firefox, repository, software-updates

About a month ago I installed Firefox on Debian. I did that, because I wanted a better functionality and Firefox ESR in Debian repo was outdated. I followed [tutorial from Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Firefox) (section From Mozilla binaries) and everything worked fine. But when I tried to update it from inside the application, it failed. I tried running it with `sudo`, but that failed too with error:

```
$sudo firefox
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: :0
```

I tried reading about what to do, but most people don't recommend running GUI application with sudo. I'd appreciate even tips about how to do it better than just to download it from Mozilla website. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you install to your home directory or to `/opt`?

Comment: I installed it to /opt.

Comment: Ok, then, to upgrade, you have to download it again and put it there, because you need root privileges to access that directory. My advice, if it fits your needs, is to install it to your local user, and then you will get automatic updates.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a single-user system (your personal laptop, for example), even if you installed in /opt  you can allow Firefox to auto-update itself by changing the ownership of the firefox directory to be your local user

```
$ cd /opt
$ sudo chmod -R [username] ./firefox
```

This is a bit unorthodox.  Normally you would install something personal into your /home/[username] directory, but this will work.  You will be able to ask Firefox to update itself through its UI by going to the menu and selecting Help->About